# Windows 7 cannot be installed to this disk

Tags: windows-7, installation, bios

I am trying to install Windows 7 from a USB onto a new computer.  The installation begins properly.  It asks me what language to use and then asks if I want to do a custom (fresh) install, which I do.  Then a screen comes up that asks me the following:

> Where do you want to install windows?

My computer's hard drive (Disk 0 Partition 1) is an option (it has 465.7 GB free). When I click on it, though, this message appears:

> Windows cannot be installed to Disk 0 Partition 1.

When I click on details, this appears:

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk.  This computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk.  Ensure that the disk's controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS menu.

Since this is a brand new computer, I was advised to click the format button.  But when I click the button format near the bottom of the window, the following message appears:

> Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing system partition.  See the setup log files for more information.

I do not know how to access the setup log files.

I do know how to access the BIOS, but I do not know how to enable the disk's controller.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "new computer" is that with an empty disc? If you can reformat as part of the install do that.

Comment: Thanks.  Reformatting was an option on the screen.  I'll try that and let you know what happens.

Comment: as drewk said, if this is a brand new hard drive - you need to format it first.

Comment: Clicking format on the "Where do you want to install windows" screen didn't work.  See my description above.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a Linux cd with gparted and make an NTFS partition. That should make Win7 happy.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  Can you provide a link to instructions for doing so?  My computer currently does not have a cd drive, just usb ports.

Comment: Go to http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download. Download an iso from there. There are also instructions there.